# jquery-ui connected sortable: how to hide/show first item?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this html markup:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Drop item here</li>
</ul>
```

When at least one item is dropped from #sortable1 to #sortable2, I'd like to add the class "hide" to:

```
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Drop item here</li>
```

just to... hide it, since this "placeholder" is now unuseful, so it becomes:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight hide">Drop item here</li>
</ul>
```

Then, if all items are dropped back from #sortable2 to #sortable1, the class `hide` should be removed again, to display the "placeholder" back

Any idea, please? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try handling the `update` event and working your way from there?

Comment: There are a number of ways you could go about try something and ask for help when you hit a snag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it...

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight placeholder">Drop item here</li>
</ul>

...

$('#sortable2').sortable({
    items: 'li:not(.placeholder)',
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    update: function(){
        var placeholder = $(this).children('.placeholder');
        ($(this).children().length > 1) ? placeholder.hide() : placeholder.show();
    }
}).disableSelection();
```